# Loading new uploaded models in viewer 401 error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm loading models in the forge viewer in a multiple model context. I currently have two loaded models. Then, trying to load another model from the same bucket, same app, i get a 401 error:
{
"developerMessage": "Token is not provided in the request.",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}

x-ads-troubleshooting: The input urn is not authorized. You're not authorized to access this object.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide some more details. How exactly are you loading the models? How did you configure the viewer, especially the `getAccessToken` function passed to `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`?

Comment: Uploaded via VSCode Forge Extension, like before. Like i said, i just added a model via the same function i loaded two (working) models before, same getAccessToken, same initializer, same bucket, same app.

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry...let'say i'm  bit of an ass and was trying accessing the bucket using the wrong client secret...

Comment: No problem :) So... no other issue here?